# Need to create and write information entered by user in swing application to a file

Tags: java, swing, io

I've created an desktop application using swings. I need to gather information inputted in the application and write that information into file when create file button is clicked. I'm quite new to this please help me. The below snippet is printing info to console but how to write it to file

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {

    String str = (String)comboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println("# Strategy: SAr, SPSL, PRISM, GANN, RRR \nstrategy="+str);

    String str1 = (String)comboBox2.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println("\n# ss1 \nsupport-strategy="+str1);

    String str2 = (String)comboBox3.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println("\n# silverm_i,silver_i,leadmini_i,lead_i,alumini_i,naturalgas_i,copperm_i,crudeoil_i,gold_i\ndata-source="+str2);

    String str3 = (String)comboBox6.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println("\n# YES or NO\npositional-trading="+str3);

    String str4 = (String)comboBox4.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println("\n# Data source options - DATABASE or CSV \ndata-from="+str4);

    String str5 = (String)comboBox5.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println("\n# DEV or DEV \nenvironment="+str5);

    String str6 = (String)comboBox7.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println("\n# Strategy: WAGHA_BORDER or REGULAR_TOP_BOTTOM_MOVEMENT_BASED_TREND (i.e. RBI) or REGULAR_TOP_BOTTOM_WITH_NO_TRADE_ZONE \ngann-strategy="+str6);
}
```

I've few date spinner object, checkboxes as well. how to gather information from those components.

Comment: Seems like you need to go through the tutorials of [Object Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html), and also [Data Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html), since the former uses the methods of the latter. If you can make a compilable, runnable example of exactly what you have, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), then one can even provide you with a working example too :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure about the **spinner object** question as it's been quite some time since I've used it, **but as for writing to a file**:

```
public void writeToFile() {
        try {

            String content = "This is the content to write into file";

            File file = new File("filename.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done writing to file.");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please reply if there are any problems.

Source: [MKYONG](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/)

## EDIT:

If you need to **read** and **update** the file, which is not in your question what-so-ever, follow nIcE cOw's references.

Comment: You know that previously you added a link with description __Oracle Documentation__, that you changed afterwards, it was related to that link. You are simply providing the incomplete information, just writing to a file is never enough, there might can be a situation, that one would want to read the same data again to update the `View`, your answer simply lacks in that direction, in my humble opinion.

Comment: If the question were to write, read and update a file, the answer would be just that, but fortunately it's not. If someone were to ask me to buy a boat, I don't go ahead and buy a port, some fishing rods, rocket launchers and a harbour along with it. Your opinion is appreciated, and only that. My opinion of my answer is that it  correlates just fine to the question and no more.

Comment: I do liked your answer no doubt (just couldn't upvote this one since my limit is gone for today, hence after 10 hours I will), since even the OP hasn't provided any valuable explanation, as to what the expectations are regarding the output, bound for the file. Might be I am wrong in making assumptions regarding the needs :-)